# Search for a website template based on a set of hex colors (a palette)

Tags: html, templates, web, search-engine

I've been looking for a service where I can input a set of color hex codes and get a list of search results of website templates matching those colors or at least close to them. Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.2createawebsite.com/build/hex-colors.html

i think you are looking for this.. please go to the site scroll a bit down and you will find a section saying "Related Shades" put your hex code and get related items

Comment: appreciate the quick response, but I'm not looking for a set of shades based on one hex code, I'm looking for a set of prebuilt website template that contains a set (or similar set) of hex codes I want. Is there anything like that?

Comment: http://flatuicolors.com/           Please have a look on this site too.. I am sure you like it also